# .NET 5.0 System.Security.Cryptography RSA.Create() Nullpointer exception

Tags: docker, cryptography, .net-5

When I run the following code

```
public SecurityKey GetAsymmetricSecurityKey(string secretKey)
{
    try
    {
        RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
        rsa.ImportFromPem(secretKey.ToCharArray());

        var keyparameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

        var key = new RsaSecurityKey(keyparameters);

        return key;
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        _logger.LogError("RSA ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        _logger.LogError(error.ToString());

        return null;
    }
}
```

I get a Null pointer exception at `RSA rsa = RSA.Create();`. It works just fine in my development environment, but when I build a Docker image of my project and create a container from it I suddenly get this error. What is going on here? How is it possible that RSA is null

## stacktrace

```
    fail: Project.Startup[0]
      RSA ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
fail: Project.Startup[0]
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Project.Logic.Workers.CryptoWorker.GetAsymmetricSecurityKey(String secretKey) in /src/Project.Logic/Workers/CryptoWorker.cs:line 176
```

## Linux Dockerfile

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "Project.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "Project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.dll"]
```

Comment: Please show the environment specifics and the full stacktrace by hitting [edit].

Comment: @MaartenBodewes oke, I don't think it will help much since all it is saying is that there is a null pointer exception. I need help from someone who understands what is going on in RSA.Create(). Maybe it needs some kind of configuration file?

Comment: It's more likely that the default RSA implementation has been replaced. `CryptoWorker` doesn't ring a bell and an Internet search doesn't show up any information either. Note that `RSA.Create()` can use any one of the implementation classes be it managed or native... So the stack trace is definitely useful. Now the trick is to find out where `CryptoWorker` is coming from.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes CryptoWorker is the class containing my GetAsymmetricSecurityKey function

Comment: Ah. Can you maybe configure your system to log a bit more? That null pointer can obviously not be part of the call to RSA.Create(), as it has no parameters. So it has to be generated internally, and in that case there should be a stacktrace. What you've given is not a stacktrace, it is a log which obviously is not configured at the `trace` or `debug` level.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes it is logging all the errors. I think somehow the static reference to RSA is null, but I don't know how that is possible

Comment: RSA is a class. There is no object, hence there is no object reference, hence the object reference cannot be null. It may be logging all the errors, but the log **level** is not low enough. I.e. you don't get enough detail if you don't see the stack trace. Maybe there is some kind of dump file next to it?